Class referred in Annotation cannot be found
In this project: https://github.com/wise-coders/groovyfx., a fork of GroovyFX (see source code). Upgrading to OpenJDK 17 and Gradle 7.6 I get this error (which did not happen under Java 8):
Could not find class for Transformation Processor groovyx.javafx.beans.FXBindableASTTransformation declared by groovyx.javafx.beans.FXBindable

The FXBindableASTTransformation is used as annotation in FXBindable.
How can I prevent this error?
You can test it by executing
cd groovyfx
gradlew build
gradlew runAccordionDemo


When do you get this error or what are you doing to get the error?

I try to run the gradle task runAccordionDemo or any other task

But the source code you are linking is the original (at first glance
this uses Gradle 6.8)?  Your changes broke it, so please provide
a [mre].

Agree. I created a fork https://github.com/wise-coders/groovyfx and updated the ticket description.

The JavaFX library has undergone significant changes, and starting from Java 11, it is no longer bundled with the JDK. Ensure you have the correct JavaFX dependencies and they are compatible with Java 17.
Solution:
Add the necessary JavaFX dependencies to your project:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-controls:17.0.1'
    implementation 'org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:17.0.1'
}

Debugging Tips:
Run your application with --show-module-resolution to see how modules are resolved and identify any issues.
Ensure that your IDE or build tool is correctly configured to use the Java 17 JDK.
